# qt sensor readingChanged() event not working altought connections are ok

Tags: android, c++, qt

I write a simple android app that save various sensor readings from adroid device(Samsung S6). But its not working after i move my project to another version of qt. I use qt 5.14.0, android sdk version 26 and ndk version 21.
My pro file looks like this:

```
    QT += core gui location positioning quickwidgets quick sensors
    CONFIG += qt console c++11 mobility

    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = RECORDER
    TEMPLATE = app
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
```

sensor creation part looks like this (for example for acceleration):

```
    mAcc = new QAccelerometer();
    mAcc->setAccelerationMode(QAccelerometer::AccelerationMode::Combined);
```

and my signal slot connection part looks like this:

```
    bool tAccConn = connect(mAcc, SIGNAL(readingChanged()), this, SLOT(mAccRead()));
    qDebug() << "Acc Connections State =" << tAccConn << "\n";
    mAcc->start();
```

The connections returns true. But slots connected to readingChanged() signals never receiving anything. Its all looks true to me. Any idea?

Edit 1. AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
     Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default features based on the dependencies of the application.
     Remove the comment if you do not require these default features. -->


<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="IMURECORDER" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
              android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity"
              android:label="RECORDER"
              android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
              android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Application arguments -->
        <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="arg1 arg2 arg3"/ -->
        <!-- Application arguments -->

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="IMURECORDER"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
        <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>

        <!-- Run with local libs -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/load_local_libs"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="jar/QtAndroid.jar:jar/QtPositioning.jar:jar/QtAndroidBearer.jar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="org.qtproject.qt5.android.positioning.QtPositioning"/>
        <!-- Used to specify custom system library path to run with local system libs -->
        <!-- <meta-data android:name="android.app.system_libs_prefix" android:value="/system/lib/"/> -->
        <!--  Messages maps -->
        <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/unsupported_android_version" android:name="android.app.unsupported_android_version"/>
        <!--  Messages maps -->

        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <!-- Orientation-specific (portrait/landscape) data is checked first. If not available for current orientation,
             then android.app.splash_screen_drawable. For best results, use together with splash_screen_sticky and
             use hideSplashScreen() with a fade-out animation from Qt Android Extras to hide the splash screen when you
             are done populating your window with content. -->
        <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_portrait" android:resource="@drawable/logo_portrait" / -->
        <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_landscape" android:resource="@drawable/logo_landscape" / -->
        <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/ -->
        <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/ -->
        <!-- Splash screen -->

        <!-- Background running -->
        <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                      application still try to draw after
                      "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                      signal is sent! -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Background running -->

        <!-- auto screen scale factor -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.auto_screen_scale_factor" android:value="false"/>
        <!-- auto screen scale factor -->

        <!-- extract android style -->
        <!-- available android:values :
            * default - In most cases this will be the same as "full", but it can also be something else if needed, e.g., for compatibility reasons
            * full - useful QWidget & Quick Controls 1 apps
            * minimal - useful for Quick Controls 2 apps, it is much faster than "full"
            * none - useful for apps that don't use any of the above Qt modules
            -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="default"/>
        <!-- extract android style -->
</activity>

<!-- For adding service(s) please check: https://wiki.qt.io/AndroidServices -->

</application>
```

Comment: did you check if the sensor is **active/busy** and how do you read sensor data in `mAccRead()` ?

Comment: can you mention which Qt version was working ?

Comment: @Redanium I was using qt 5.12.4. I am reading sensor data like this:               
           **AccReader = mAcc->reading();
           AccX = AccReader->x();
           AccY = AccReader->y();
           AccZ = AccReader->z();**

Comment: @Redanium and i just check the sensor. after i start mAcc, sensor isBusy() and isActive() both returning false.

Comment: `isActive()` returning `false` meaning that the sensor is not active so don't expect reading . can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: @Redanium i added xml file to post.

Comment: check this [Qt for Android known issues](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues)  , you have to update your `AndroidManifest.xml` to work with `Qt 5.14.x`